# Discord.py - bot doesn't respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm building a Discord bot on Python and have an issue in code.
Here's my entire code:

```
import discord
from discord import message
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='_')

gret_words = ['hi', 'grets', 'greetings', 'mornin', 'hey']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}! My name is Bot-3P0!')

async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in gret_words:
        await message.channel.send("Nice to see you!")

####################


client.run('TOKEN')
```

But my issue is that, when I type in messenger one word from the `gret_words` list, the bot literally doesn't react! I'll be grateful for all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark `on_message` as an event. Simply add `@client.event` on top of `async def on_message(message)` and it should work! Edit: you will need to add `client.process_commands()` to your `on_message()` as well

Comment: Tell him to add `process_commands` as well. The commands will not run otherwise.